# Javascript construction: variable *is set* but must be *null*

Tags: javascript, jquery

Problem is: context variable *_curIndex* is set when there is first call of switchTo (*at point a*):

```
function ShowSwitcherObject( id, switchIds )
{

    this._id = id;

    this._isInited = false;

    this.isInited = function()
    {
        return this._isInited;
    };

    this._visible = false;

    this.show = function()
    {
        if( this._visible == false )
        {
            $( '#' + this._id ).show();
            this._visible = true;
            this._isInited = true;
        }
    };

    this._showSwitch = function()
    {
        $( '#' + this._switchIds[ this._curIndex ] ).show();
    };

    this._hideSwitch = function()
    {
        $( '#' + this._switchIds[ this._curIndex ] ).hide();
    };

    this.switchTo = function( index )
    {       
        if( index != this._curIndex ) // point a
        {
            if( this._curIndex != null )
            {
                this._hideSwitch();
            }

            this._curIndex = index; // point b
            this._showSwitch();
        }
    };
    this._switchIds = switchIds;
    return this;
}
```

It's interesting that if we comment *point b* the variable is *null* at point a.
There are no external sets of *_curIndex*. It could be only set by *switchTo*. Is it firefox bug or something else?

Comment: How is the function called? What is 'this' set to? What happens to it elsewhere? It is unlikely that anybody can debug a snippet of your code in isolation.

Comment: It's interesting that if we comment point b the variable is null at point a.

Comment: Read this in addition to the correct answer below: http://saladwithsteve.com/2008/02/javascript-undefined-vs-null.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code it seems `this._curIndex` would be `undefined` at point a.

If you need `this._curIndex` to be null, you must set it to null yourself, since the Javascript interpreter doesn't resolve uninitialized variables to `null`, but rather `undefined`.

Try this instead:

```
this.switchTo = function( index )
{       
    if( index != this._curIndex ) // point a
    {
        if( typeof(this._curIndex) != 'undefined' )
        {
            this._hideSwitch();
        }

        this._curIndex = index; // point b
        this._showSwitch();
    }
};
```

Comment: It must be undefined but it's not undefined. Excuse me please Jens.

Comment: In according to my knowledge of Javascript it's strange.

Comment: OK, thank you very much! My decision is to do: *this._curIndex=null* in body of object function *ShowSwitcherObject*. It works.

Comment: @Jamiec: `(this._currIndex)` is a valid expression that you can pass to the `typeof` operator. Go try `typeof(5+5)` in your console.

Comment: Indeed it was a misunderstanding. Firebug sometimes stores an old value of variable after update of a page.

Comment: And it's true that typeof isn't a 'real' function, so the parentheses in `typeof(this._curIndex)` are technically optional, but I always include the parentheses anyway for the sake of readability

Answer (score 2):

Uninitialized variables in Javascript have the value of `undefined`, not `null`.

```
this.switchTo = function( index )
{       
   alert(this._curIndex === undefined);
   // ...
};
```

The above does alert `true` **only** on the first call - which means `_curIndex` behaves at it should.

Also note that:

```
alert(undefined != null);   // returns false
alert(undefined !== null);  // returns true
```